# Tomcat SSL error : keytool error: java.lang.exception: failed to establish chain from reply

Tags: tomcat, keystore, business-intelligence, keytool, business-objects

So i have been trying to configure SSL on Tomcat for SAP BI 4.3.
I use the generic steps to create keystore, generate csr, import the root certificate (.pem) using -trustcacerts and import the signed certificate (.pem)

However while importing the signed certificate i get the subjected error.

I have seen previous blogs on the same but no luck to solve this.

We are using an internal CA to sign the CSR as opposed to GoDaddy, Verisign etc.
There is no intermediate CA certificate available for the same, only root and signed certificates is what I have received.

When I list my keystore I get 1 private key 1 trustca certificate(which I imported)

Any help is appreciated!

Tried to import the signed certificate in the keystore.
Expected the signed certificate to be imported.
Actual result leaded to keytool error: java.lang.exception: failed to establish chain from reply

Comment: Your cert is not in fact "signed by" (issued directly under) that root. (Aside: issuing a cert is NOT done by signing the CSR.) Either (1) you have the wrong root, (2) there is in fact an intermediate even though you say there isn't, or (3) you have the wrong EE cert (unlikely, since key match was checked first and should be unique). Look at the subject/owner and issuer of each cert and figure out what is correct and what is not. But this is not programming or development.